PostgreSQL: Is there any way to further optimise ASYNC replication towards less data loss during failover?
We are looking to see if there any further optimisations that can be done in PostgreSQL(13) ASYNC replication to make data loss near to zero as possible when a failover is triggered during disaster. We don't want change to synchronous replication as with the testing the TPS is really low comparing with ASYNC method.
We see an average write lag of 200-300KBs and at peak traffic up to 20MB. Is there any optimisations can do on WAL level? Any other area to tune?
UPDATE
Could wal_compression help optimise this?

Figure out why the lag is as high as it is, and improve it.  Maybe it is just a matter of network latency?  Is the problem the 200-300kB case, or is the problem only the 20MB case?

@jjanes We are trying to optimise the setup towards least data loss in case of disaster. (e.g 20KB loss instead of 200KB, 2MB instead of 20MB depends on the traffic during the time). Without improving the hardware is there any tuning possible on Postgres level to do the same?

I don't know of any magic parameters.  You need to find the bottleneck first, I'd start by running top (or other system monitoring tool) on each side .  Also, don't dismiss synchronous replication out of hand.  Of course it lowers the TPS in a simple test.  But how much of a problem is that for your use case?  Can you make up for it just by increasing simultaneous connections?

In my simple testing using pgbench I see a difference of ≈70 % TPS drop when in SYNC mode. That much drop can't tolerate. Increasing connections you mean max_wal_senders?

Is it wal_compression good? I see TPS increase and less I/O but on the network I really can't find any improvement. So many blogs says so at least for random update. Maybe my testing not good?

No increased connections mean whatever client is sending the commands.  In your benchmark case, that would be pgbench, by using the -c switch.

I wouldn't expect wal_compression to help if the problem is latency, rather than throughput.  But if it increased TPS than I guess it worked, I don't know what you mean about not finding improvement.  Isn't an increased TPS an improvement?
